# PNG with black background that inherits opacity and becomes transparent

Tags: css, png, transparency, alpha

```css
#wrapper { 
   padding: 20px;
 background-image: url('http://s492610445.online.de/images/background.jpg')
}
#a { 
  padding: 25px;  
  background: #000; 
  opacity: 0.7;  
}
h2 { font-family: sans-serif; color: #fff; margin: 5px 0; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h2>orig. Image</h2>
  <img src="http://s492610445.online.de/cat/pizza.png" />
  <div id="a">
      <h2>Image in tag with 0.7 opacity</h2>
      <img src="http://s492610445.online.de/cat/pizza.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm confused about a css rule. I am making some adjustments on a page and I saw something, I have newer seen before. There is a `PNG` with black background, and when a parent tag has a black background too and has a opacity-value < 1 than the black parts of the `PNG` will become transparent too. How is this possible?

Comment: Did you notice that the not-so-black parts turn transparent as well. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: maybe for you. Try the same in photoshop. You will see, that there is a difference. It looks like, that the browser is precomposing the whole div (with opacity rule) into a png and than its making this transparent. For me its not the excepted behavior.

Comment: OK, Photoshop example then. Open pizza.png in Photoshop. Place a layer with solid black color _behind_ it. Place both layers inside a layer set. Set opacity the opacity of the _layer set_ to 70%. Place background.jpg behind the layer set and observe the result.

Answer (score 0):

The child element inherits opacity from parent. So, any background image (and everything else) will become transparent in such case.
**Opacity will effect every inner element.**

Comment: You missunderstood it. The black parts of the child-png become 100% transparent. And the other parts are inhering the e.G. opacity: 0.9. Check it here: http://s392610445.online.de/index.php?content=pizza => Unter the pizzaimage is a png with text "pizza". Download it and you will understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the containing `<a>` to have an opacity of 0.7, the contained `<img>` becomes transparent too. In fact it becomes transparent throughout the whole image, not just the black portions (although that's not immediately obvious).

If you want a transparent background, set the background colour to be transparent:

```css
#wrapper { 
   padding: 20px;
 background-image: url('http://s392610445.online.de/images/background.jpg')
}
#a { 
  padding: 25px;  
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
}
h2 { font-family: sans-serif; color: #fff; margin: 5px 0; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h2>orig. Image</h2>
  <img src="http://s392610445.online.de/cat/pizza.png" />
  <div id="a">
      <h2>Image in tag with 0.7 opacity</h2>
      <img src="http://s392610445.online.de/cat/pizza.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** Here is what your code looks like in Chrome for me:

[image]

Comment: "the contained <img> becomes transparent..." That not corrent. The black parts become 100% transparent and the rest of the png inherits 0.7. I just want to understand, how the browsers are handling this.

Comment: @KevinTurner, what browser are you using? In my browser (Chrome) I don't see what you're describing. Could you attach a screenshot to your question?